# Allowing multiple IPs under Azure SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have placed the installation scripts and files on Blob storage at Azure.

Now I want only specific users/clients to access this storage area and download the installation scripts and files.

In order to accomplish this, I'm using Shared Access Signatures (SAS). So I Generate SAS for script file(s). But when it comes to "Allowed IP addresses", I can only specify one IP address or range of IP addresses. While I've 3 different clients at moment (which will increase in future), and they all have their different IP addresses. So how can I specify these 3 separate IPs in here?

Any assistance in this matter is highly appreciated. Also if there is any other possible / recommended solution for my requirement then please guide me to that as well, if possible. I'm open to any alternate better option.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how can I specify these 3 separate IPs in here?

In a single SAS, you can either specify a single IP address (e.g. 10.2.1.80) or an IP address range (10.2.1.80-10.2.1.90).

In your case, you will need to generate a separate SAS token for each client with their respective IP address.

Comment: When I'll generate separate SAS token for other client won't it invalidate or remove previous token which I shared with earlier client?

Comment: No it won't invalidate the other tokens. Essentially Azure Storage does not store the SAS tokens anywhere. It validates the SAS token when it receives a request via SAS URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaurav.
I'll verify this explanation and mark this as answer.

Meantime, do you suggest or feel that the solution i'm using for my scenario is practical or there is other recommendation for such use case in Azure?

Comment: I think the solution you're thinking about is the easiest and most practical.